# How to find out what device a file or folder is on?

Tags: hardware, command-line, devices

Is it possible to query (using the command line) what device a particular file or folder is on?

All files are on some sort of storage device (eg. `/dev/sda1`). These storage devices are mounted at a particular point in the file system hierarchy (eg. `/`, `/home`).

I want to find out what device a file is on. For example, if `/dev/sda3` is mounted on `/home`, given the file  `~/document.odt`, what command can I use to determine that the file is on `/dev/sda3`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
df /path/to/filename
```

It will show the path base mount point.

Comment: The -h option (`df -h`) is also useful.

Comment: yes -h  is very nice  (  show in human readable format )